# Make any column autoGenerate (Not Primary Key) in Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

**I want to auto generate**

> ID // auto but not primary

**Column and set**

> productID // primary not auto

**as the primary key...
Is it possible or my idea is wrong...?
if my idea is wrong then please give me the write info... 
thanks**

```
//@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@Nullable  // I want to autogenerate this "ID" column 
private long ID;

@ColumnInfo(name = "pCategorySubID")
@SerializedName("pCategorySubID")
@Expose
private String pCategorySubID;

@PrimaryKey // this is my primary key
@ColumnInfo(name = "ProductID")
@SerializedName("ProductID")
@Expose
@NonNull
private String productID;
```

Comment: Room is built on top of sqlite, right? In it, only an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column is auto-generated when not given a value when inserting a row (Since it's just an alias for the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).). You'll have to maintain a counter yourself for other columns.

Comment: I think that's not possible, also it appears something in your logic is flawed, since why would you require an auto-generated integer, that's not a primary key? It would probably be not of any use. I think you should post your requirement, and people here will help you out with the alternatives.

Comment: @Debanjan this could happen if you are working on offline first app with list of items. Room DB do not respect the insertion order thus it could return items in random order. What if the entity already has an id and the order of items should be the same from the way it was first inserted? I think that is a valid use case.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS This is almost 4 years, but I think in your case, the best thing to use would be the timestamp, and order based on that 
System.currentTimeInMillis()