# Make a field autoGenerate other than Primary key in Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, primary-key, android-room

First of all this is a duplicate question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941967/make-any-column-autogenerate-not-primary-key-in-room-persistence-library), I couldn't find any correct answer for that one, thats why I'm asking an other one.

My requirement is to have same entity used by many users. For that I have created an entity and assigned userId and infoId together as primary key(composite key) for it. Here I'm expecting infoId to be autogenerated. But I failed to make it so.

Example:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"infoId", "userId"})
public class SaveInfo {

private int infoId;
private Info info;
private int userId;

.....
// Constructor setters and getters
.....
}
```

I have tried putting column info for infoId, but which is not working

```
 @ColumnInfo(index = true)
 private int infoId;
```

Simply this is how my table should look like.

```
info   infoId   userId
-----------------------
ASFAS    1        123
VGVGG    2        236
VHAFD    3        123
ASFAS    4        236
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try setting infoId and userId primary key by

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var infoId: String = "",
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var userId: String = "",
```

Please note I am using Kotlin

Comment: This isn't possible as it results in this error: "You cannot have multiple primary keys defined in an Entity."